# How to print prefix int 0 in a series of numbers 1-9 in for loop?

Tags: dart

How to print prefix int 0 in a series of numbers 1-9 using '**for**' loop?

```
   void main() {
  var id;
  for (id = 01; id <= 60; id++) {
    print("10HN1A04$id");
  }
}
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT:**
10HN1A0**41**
10HN1A0**42**
10HN1A0**43**
10HN1A0**44**
10HN1A0**45**
10HN1A0**46**
10HN1A0**47**
10HN1A0**48**
10HN1A0**49**
10HN1A0410
10HN1A0411
10HN1A0412
10HN1A0413
10HN1A0414
10HN1A0415
10HN1A0416
10HN1A0417
10HN1A0418
10HN1A0419
10HN1A0420

**REQUIRED OUTPUT**
10HN1A0**401**
10HN1A0**402**
10HN1A0**403**
10HN1A0**404**
10HN1A0**405**
10HN1A0**406**
10HN1A0**407**
10HN1A0**408**
10HN1A0**409**
10HN1A0410
10HN1A0411
10HN1A0412
10HN1A0413
10HN1A0414
10HN1A0415
10HN1A0416
10HN1A0417
10HN1A0418
10HN1A0419
10HN1A0420

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [String.padLeft](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/String/padLeft.html).

```
void main() {
  var id;
  for (id = 01; id <= 60; id++) {
    print("10HN1A04${id.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NumberFormat class for that, see the [NumberFormat-class documentation](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/intl/latest/intl/NumberFormat-class.html).

```
void main() {
    var nf = new NumberFormat("00");
    var id;
    for (id = 01; id <= 60; id++) {
       print("10HN1A04");
       print nf.format(id);
    }
 }
```

(note: untested)

Comment: Thank you for the response.